# Remove Gaps between Slider and Footer Div in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive image slider that i have downloaded from internet and it was supposed to take full screen length Which i am trying to reduce height and add into my webpage.The image of the slider is getting resized and image is showing properly but the container size is not getting reduced due to which there is whitespace between slider and next Div.Now after the slider i have footer Div .The working is fine for both ie. slider and footer.The weird thing is the display .There is some gap between Slider and Footer Div .I tried everything to remove it but in vain only So posting here.

Here is the HTML..

```
    <ul id="demo1" class="slides">
<li>
    <img src="slides/add1.jpg" />
    <!--Slider Description example-->
    <div class="slide-desc">
            <h2>Slider Title 1</h2>

        <p>Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. <a class="more" href="#">more</a>

        </p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="slides/add2.jpg" />
    <div class="slide-desc">
            <h2>Slider Title 2</h2>

        <p>Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. <a class="more" href="#">more</a>

        </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

```
 <div id="footer" class="footer-shadow">
 <p>Hello Its me!!!</p>
 </div>
```

And here is the fiddle that i have created.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/pvxa4trb/1/)

The code in the fiddle is long but i was not to short it as the probem could not be explained properly.
Please help me to remove the gaps between the two.

Thank you.

Comment: @ChakravarthySM I am not able to find out `top:0px;` ..

Comment: @ChakravarthySM Do we need to change something in the jquery script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/pvxa4trb/12/)

Well, there are somethings i have observed into your code:

**First of all For CSS Change** there is no requirement for the `bottom:0px` into `li` element:

Whenever there is a `bottom:0px` and `top:0px` have given in the css, at that time they consider 100% height for the parent div.

Same thing happened with 'right:0px' and 'left:0px'. If its given both than they will consider 100% width for the parent div.

So remove `'bottom': '0'` from  `slides.each(function () {` function.

Also,

There is no requirement to giving padding into `.skdslider:after`  and `.skdslider` class.

Instead give dynamic height using jQuery.

**For JS**

Add this line into your function:

```
$('.skdslider  .slides').css('height',$('.slides li').innerHeight());
```

Comment: OK .I got it Now one small query Still some space is there between slider and footer .How to remove that ?

Comment: Its due to margin in the p tag. Add css like following: .footer-shadow p { margin:0px; }

Comment: I have added that still some space is there .I want to remove that also.Here is the updated fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/vikas13pandey/pvxa4trb/16/`

Comment: Mate, that space is due to default line height. If you doesn't want that too than set line-height:0px :  .footer-shadow p { line-height:0px; margin:0px; }

Comment: Still Same problem.I have added one div between slider and footer .Please see fiddle..`http://jsfiddle.net/vikas13pandey/pvxa4trb/21/`

Comment: i'm checking, I'll let you know once i found solution.

Comment: I think sir the size of the container is not getting reduced

Comment: Sir Please provide me your mail id i will send you the Webpage alongwith all jquery and css.Please sir

Answer (score -1):

The slider plugin you are using adds `:after` selector to slider DOM which has some CSS properties including padding-top. Removing that should help...

Just remove reduce padding-top:50% in after property of .skslider. That is causing the huge padding after slider DOM.

```
.skdslider:after {
content: '';
padding-top: 50%; //Decrease this.....
display: block;
}
```